# Best practices for C++ development in quantitative finance

Tags: option-pricing, programming

I'm been working as a quant for the past 10 years, but have managed to avoid any significant C++ projects until now. I typically use a combination of kdb, R, and python.

I've now been tasked with building a medium size options pricing and execution system in C++.

Are there any best practices for this kind of work, particularly any that diverge from general C++ best practices.  I'm thinking things like C++ version, build system, package management, testing framework, math libraries, etc.

I'll be using Linux and don't need to integrate with any other code except through standard network protocols.

Comment: 10 years whilst managing to avoid significant c++ projects: I hear you! Pretty much on the same boat :) Curious to read answers to your question!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is very opinion based, and likely is better suited to StackOverflow.

Comment: A good read is always "C++ Design Patterns and Derivatives Pricing" by Mark S. Joshi.

Comment: Does this help: [Architecture of a global pricing library with immutable payoffs](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/44450/architecture-of-a-global-pricing-library-with-immutable-payoffs)?

Comment: you can start by reviewing code/documentation for https://www.quantlib.org/   .it's not bad for fixed income.

Comment: @oliversm why would stackoverflow be better?  It's a highly domain-specific question..

Comment: @robsmith11 there is no mention about what features specific to finance are desirable compared to any other software development project. This makes the question quite open ended and opinion based. Additionally, without mentioning what it is about finance that needs special attention this really is no better defined than any generic software development project, and hence I suspect SO would be a better forum to discuss this.

Comment: @chrisaycock your comment would have been been a good answer.  I don't understand the obsession with closing "open ended" questions on stack exchange websites.

Comment: @robsmith11 Your question doesn't have an answer; it only invites discussion, which is [not what Stack Exchange is for](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/). The sites that do allow discussions [ [1](https://www.quora.com/topic/Quantitative-Finance), [2](https://forum.wilmott.com), [3](https://www.nuclearphynance.com) ] have a low signal-to-noise ratio. When you get stuck on an actual hard problem, you'd be hard-pressed to find experts who can help you.

Comment: I have withdrawn my original comment. I don't know why someone would demand that you use a specific language but not tell you *how* to use that language. The person who told you to use C++ should also have told you which build system and testing framework to use.